# How were multiple vacuum pumps used to raise water over 10m (e.g. by a steam engine)?

Tags: pumps, engineering-history

I can imagine a steam engine driving multiple regular old vacuum pumps, which each raise water ~10m.  I would think that someone would combine the multiple pumps into a single piece of machinery for raising water >10m without high pressure.

Was such a thing in use before the Newcomen steam engine (driven by horses or something)?  How was it designed?  Was the same pumping system used with the Newcomen steam engine?

Comment: what do you think causes the 10m limit? And then, how would you put all the pumps in one device?

Comment: Mike, the tallest column of water you can lift by vacuum is 10 m. (Same principle as the mercury barometer which maxes at 750 mm.)

Comment: @transistor why do you think I asked???? I was hoping the OP would be able to expand their knowledge by a bit of research... Just to help you though the theoretical limit is 10.34m (assuming perfect conditions like perfect vacuum etc) but a "real" limit is closer to 8 or 9 m due to losses, imperfect seals etc.

Comment: I'm aware of what causes the limit, and I'm wondering if & how they actually implemented it in one device.

Comment: It's rare (if ever) that someone would chain vacuum pumps.  It's far easier to place a pump at the bottom (or near the bottom) of the setup and just push water as high as you like.

Answer (score 2):

pumps called mechanical lift pumps existed before then. these had the piston/cylinder and check valve assembly deep in the hole. actuating the piston with a long rod lifted one cylinder's worth of water upwards in the well pipe after which a check valve closed and held the water in place. pushing the piston down opened another valve and refilled the cylinder, etc. such a pump can lift water higher than a vacuum pump can but it requires a long actuating rod to connect the handle with the piston.

Comment: Please punctuate and capitalise properly if you wish to be taken seriously.

Comment: @transistor, when my typing is no longer impaired by a broken wrist, i will consider your request. in the meantime i will leave elegance to tailors and focus on being correct. -niels

Comment: Good man. I hope you can get back on the bass soon.

Comment: god I hope so, this would represent the first time in 48 years that the bass is off-limits. getting x-rays soon.

Comment: I helped a friend replace the leather valve flaps in his well.  The connecting rod links were hardwood, 3/4" square with a ferrule and hook.  Each rod was about 10 feet. He was pumping water from about 140 feet.

Comment: 140 feet of connecting rod, that's serious stuff!